# Can't receive broadcasted event in client using socket.io

Tags: javascript, socket.io, ejs

I'm trying to render some data on `active.ejs` which has a socket that is listening for the event `users`. The event `users` is emitted as a broadcast by `index.js`.

I have a `console.log("do you go here")` in my socket listener function in `active.ejs`. 
However, it never logs "do you go here" in `socket.on` so that means somehow the broadcast emitted by `index.js` isn't received by `active.ejs`. How do I get it to receive it?

**index.js**

```
var io = socket(server);
io.on('connection', function(socket){
  count++;
  socket.broadcast.emit('users', socket.handshake.query);
});
```

**active.ejs**

```
    ..html boilerplate
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="http://localhost:4000/socket.io/socket.io.js"></script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <p>
      Welcome,
      <%= user_info.uri %>
    </p>
    <div id="active"></div>
    <script>
    var socket = io.connect('http://localhost:4000/tune-in', {query: <%- JSON.stringify(user_info) %>});
    var active = document.getElementById('active');

    // Listening for events on socket
    socket.on('users', function(data){
      console.log('do you go here');
      active.innerHTML += "<p><em>" + data.display_name + " is connected" + "</em></p>";
    });
    </script>
  </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code `socket.broadcast.emit('users', socket.handshake.query);` does exactly what it should - sends event to all clients except the client that has just connected.
You may want to use `io.emit('users', socket.handshake.query)` instead.

EDITED:

Add the namespace to the server:

```
var io = socket(server);
io.of('/tune-in').on('connection', function(socket){
  count++;
  socket.broadcast.emit('users', socket.handshake.query);
});
```

Comment: That's exactly what I want it to do, send event to all clients except the one that just connected. When I have two open browsers, with two clients connected for instance, I want each one to show the other one (but not itself) as an `active` client in the `div` with `id="active"`. However, the `socket.on` function isn't firing.